# Accurate of navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Tags: javascript, geolocation

How accurate is result of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` function?
When it can return low-quality results?

Comment: it depends of the device right ? Smartphone / Desktop etc...

Comment: Like @Awea said, most desktop browsers don't have GPS so its based on IP address instead. I live in a city of 50,000 people (not giant but not small either) and `getCurrentPosition()` in Firefox shows me about 100 miles away in a larger city.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the below

http://www.thedotproduct.org/2010/04/accurate-geo-location-from-apple-iphone-using-navigator-geolocation/

Bear in mind that behind the scene this API uses the mobile cell towers and their signal strengths so it may be not really accurate(it could return few locations against one positions)

Answer (score 2):

It depence from type of connection too:

- WiFi ~20m
- GPS ~10m
- GSM ~1km

Comment: What your source to say this ? getCurrentPosition for me, a WIFI's user, return Paris (where my provider is) and not my current location, Marseille ^^. So WIFI ~800 KM ? :p